# Odd spacing due to diagonal dots in pmatrix environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, matrices, arrays

I'm trying to typeset this matrix, but it seems the spacing between the fourth and fifth lines is off, perhaps due to the diagonal dots :

[image: matrix]

Here is my Latex code :

```
\[ \mathrm{Mat}_{\mathcal B}D = \begin{pmatrix}
1   & 1      & 0      &        &        &   \\
0   & 1      & 2      & \ddots &        &   \\
    & \ddots & \ddots & 3      & \ddots &   \\
    &        &        & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
    & (0)    &        & \ddots & 1      & n \\
    &        &        &        & 0      & 1 \end{pmatrix}\]
```

What could I do to fix this up ?

Comment: owing to the way `\ddots` is defined, that "symbol" is taller than any digit or letter.  if you are willing to have the wider separation, then put `\phantom{\ddots}` in an empty cell on the last line.  if you would rather "tighten up" the lines, then you'll need to redefine `\ddots` to get rid of the extra height.  `\smash{\ddots}` should do the trick there; should be safe since every row does have something else in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tabstackengine` package has a `\fixTABwidth{T}` macro to force all columns to be equal width (based on the widest column).  In addition to that, I just set the intercolumn gap with `\setstacktabbedgap{}` and the vertical baselineskip with `\setstackgap{L}{}`, to achieve whatever spacing is preferred, using a `\parenMatrixstack` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\setstacktabbedgap{.4em}
\fixTABwidth{T}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathrm{Mat}_{\mathcal B}D = \parenMatrixstack{
1   & 1      & 0      &        &        &   \\
0   & 1      & 2      & \ddots &        &   \\
    & \ddots & \ddots & 3      & \ddots &   \\
    &        &        & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
    & (0)    &        & \ddots & 1      & n \\
    &        &        &        & 0      & 1 }\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the vertical space between the final two rows of your matrix being smaller than that between other rows, the *horizontal* space between the first two columns (and between the final two columns) is smaller than that between the other columns. The first issue arises because the *height* of the `\ddots` glyph is -- assuming you're using the Computer Modern font family and a main document font size of 10pt -- is `15.1pt`, whereas that of `0` and `1` is just `6.4pt`. The second issue arises because the *width* of the `\ddots` glyph is `11.7pt`, whereas that of `0` and `1` is just `5pt`.

The easiest remedy, already suggested by barbara beeton in a comment, is to insert an `\hphantom{\ddots}` ("horizontal phantom", has width of `\ddots` but no height or depth) instruction in the top-right cell of the matrix, and a `\phantom{\ddots}` ("phantom" with width, height, and depth of `\ddots`) instruction in the bottom-left cell of the matrix.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ 
\mathrm{Mat}_{\mathcal B}D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1   & 1      & 0      &        &        & \hphantom{\ddots}  \\
0   & 1      & 2      & \ddots &        &   \\
    & \ddots & \ddots & 3      & \ddots &   \\
    &        &        & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
    & (0)    &        & \ddots & 1      & n \\
\phantom{\ddots}  & & &        & 0      & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

*Aside*: If you have very sharp vision, you'll probably notice that the horizontal distance between columns 1 and 2 (and 2 and 3) of the matrix still isn't perfectly the same as that between the other columns. That's because the width of `\ddots` is `11.7pt` (as was noted earlier), whereas the width of the entry `(0)` in the second column is `12.8pt`. Given the overall sparseness of the matrix, I'd say this width discrepancy is not material; it certainly shouldn't distract from the ability to "read" the matrix. (However, if you're a stickler for typographic perfection, you might want to load the `mathtools` package instead of the `amsmath` package and replace `(0)` with `\mathclap{(0)}`.)

Comment: Thank you for the details on where the issue comes from: I didn't even notice the horizontal spacing issue ! I didn't know about the `\mathclap` command, and I shall use it from now on.